# Unable to open Ubuntu after installation on Sony Vaio

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows-8, vaio

I had Windows 8 64 bit preinstalled on Sony Vaio Model:SVF15213SNB.
I then booted from the Ubuntu 14.04 USB drive and I created root,home,swap out of a 20 GB partition.
On restart it then showed GRUB where I chose the Windows 8 to boot into, I then restarted but this time GRUB didn't load and Windows 8 automatically started.
I then tried to reinstall Ubuntu and during the setup it showed that I already had Ubuntu 14.04 installed on the system.
I chose the option "Replace Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS" hence removing the old Ubuntu installation and replace it with a new installation.
After the installation GRUB didnt load and it automatically booted Ubuntu 14.04. There I saw that the whole hard disk had been formatted and the new installation covered all of it.

Now another problem came up and the problem is that the new installation of Ubuntu cant start and it repeatedly shows the Sony Vaio Care Rescue mode where I am stuck and I can neither install Windows nor remove Ubuntu.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete all of the Ubuntu partitions that were created when you first installed it.
2. Start the install again and get to where you re-partition your drive.
3. Set up your partitions how you like them.
4. Before going on, towards the bottom of the window, choose to install the bootloader to the EFI system partition.
5. Continue with the install normally. When you restart your computer, grub should come up.

You can find more information about it here: http://itsfoss.com/install-ubuntu-1404-dual-boot-mode-windows-8-81-uefi/

EDIT: Addressing the last part, try to open your BIOS by restarting your computer and pressing F2 until it appears. In the BIOS, (typically in the last menu) there should be an option to select a boot device. Here you can select a drive to re-install either Ubuntu or Windows 8.

Regarding the "Sony Vaio Care Rescue", couldn't you just follow through with this and restore your computer? I don't have experience with Sony Vaio computers, so correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I am unable to boot from the Live USB/Live CD of either ubuntu or windows.

Comment: Regarding the "Sony Vaio Care Rescue" it seems that the recovery partitions have also got corrupted because whenever I choose the option of recovering the system it shows an error and I am forced to return to the screen of Sony Vaio Care Rescue